# How do I get this to output with GCD recursion

Tags: java, recursion

This is what it should look like

```
Calling: gcd(20,12) 
  Calling: gcd(12,8) 
    Calling: gcd(8,4) 
      Calling: gcd(4,0) 
        Returning: 4 from gcd(4,0) 
      Returning: 4 from gcd(8,4) 
    Returning: 4 from gcd(12,8) 
  Returning: 4 from gcd(20,12) 
Returning: 4 from gcd(12,20)
```

this is my output

```
Calling: gcd(10,16)
  Calling: gcd(16,10)
    Calling: gcd(10,6)
      Calling: gcd(6,4)
        Calling: gcd(4,2)
          Returning: 2 from gcd(2,0)
```

this is my code

```
public static int gcd(int x, int y, String indent) {
        if (y == 0) {
            System.out.println(indent + "Returning: " + x + " from gcd(" + x + "," + y + ")");
            return x;
        } else {
            System.out.println(indent + "Calling: gcd(" + x + "," + y + ")");
            indent = indent + "  ";
            return gcd(y, x % y, indent);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Add a print describing the return in your `else` block.

Comment: You need to print "calling" first in the body of the method and print "returning" before the return statement.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you only print "Returning" when y is zero. That only happens once.  What you want to do is for each "calling", it has to be paired with a "returning".

In other words, you need to print "calling" at the start of the body of the method and print "returning" before the return statement.

```
    public static int gcd(int x, int y, String ind){
       System.out.println(ind + "Calling: gcd(" + x + "," + y + ")");  //<<
       int max = Math.max(x,y), min = Math.min(x,y);
       int result = (min == 0 ? max : gcd(max%min,min,ind+ind));
       System.out.println(ind + "Returning: gcd(" + x + "," + y + ")"); //<<
       return result;
    }
```

Comment: First of all thank you! Second, does returning not print until after because the recursion occurs the line before?